# How can i create a progress bar that has more than two steps?

Tags: wpf, wix, installation, bootstrapper, burn

My progress bar only moves twice during the execute process.

I've created a custom WiX Bootstrapper application using WPF. During the execute phase I'd like to show a detailed progress bar, but the progress event is only fired twice. This means the progress bar only moves twice during the process.

```cs
this.Bootstrapper.Progress += this.OnProgress;

private void OnProgress(object sender, ProgressEventArgs e)
{
    Bootstrapper.Engine.Log(LogLevel.Standard, "OnProgress: Progress: " + e.OverallPercentage);
    Progress = e.OverallPercentage;
}
```

I would expect the progress event to be fired more times thus enabling me to show a nicer progress bar.

Does anyone have any experience with this? Is there a way to provide a better experience of progress for the end user?

Comment: Just a link for now: [Stropek's sample](https://github.com/rstropek/Samples/tree/master/WiXSamples/CustomBurnUI/InstallerUI) (what came to mind off the bat, not investigated). [One more](https://bryanpjohnston.com/2012/09/28/custom-wix-managed-bootstrapper-application/comment-page-1/).

Comment: Have you tried `this.Bootstrapper.ExecuteProgress += this.OnProgress` instead of `this.Bootstrapper.Progress += this.OnProgress` ?